# Generating Different Pages by one Page. (HTML and JS)

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

I am trying to create a polls website, where you can create a poll with multiple options, customized title and theme color.

I already know how to create the page where you can create you poll, I am using Firebase to storage them, each one with an ID. And this is how I am Storaging them in Firebase Realtime Database:

[image]

But now, for each polls created and want an different link, for example: "site-url.com/#1" for ID 1, "site-url.com/#2" for ID 2 and so go on.

I also already have the "template page" where it reads the database and show the polls with its Title, Options and Color. And an 404 page, in case someone tries to go to an non-existing ID page.

Comment: You can parse `window.location.hash` to get the values like `"#1"` and `"#2"` to determine what request for data you make ... if that is what you are asking...not 100% clear what you are asking

Comment: guess that would work, I'll try it thanks